# Fully faithful aspheric functors are locally aspheric.

Tags: category-theory

I was trying to prove the claim in the title, that is, fully faithful aspheric functors are locally aspheric, and I came up with a proof which I believe is false, but I can't pin down why. This is stated without proof in a paper by Maltsiniotis as an example of locally aspheric functor.
For completeness' sake : By aspheric, I mean $W$-aspheric, where $W$ is a collection of arrows in $Cat$ which is weakly saturated, contains the functor $A\to e$ for any $A$ with a final object (where $e$ denotes a final object in $Cat$) and such that for $f:A\to B$,  if $f/b : A/b\to B/b$ is in $W$ for all $b\in B$, then $f\in W$.
A functor $f:A\to B$ is called aspheric if for all object $b\in B$ the map $f/b:A/b\to B/b$ is in $W$. It is called locally aspheric if instead for all $a\in A$ the functor $A/a\to B/f(a)$ is in $W$.

Given $a\in A$, we still denote $f:A/a\to B/f(a)$ the functor induced by $f$, we want to show that for all $a\in A$ $f:A/a\to B/f(a)$ is aspheric. But earlier in the paper, it is shown that a functor $g:X\to Y$ is aspheric if and only if for all $y\in Y$ $X/y$ is aspherical (which is defined as $X/y\to e$ is aspherical or equivalently is in $W$).
Given what precedes we want to show the following statement :

If $f:A\to B$ is fully faithful and aspheric, then for all $a\in A$, and for all $(c:b\to f(a))\in B/f(a)$, $(A/a)/c$ is aspherical.

Fix $a\in A$, and $c:b\to f(a)$. Objects of $A/a$ are pairs $(a', a'\to a)$ or simply maps $a'\to a$ for $a'\in A$. A morphism between $a'\to a$ and $a''\to a$, is a map $a'\to a''$ making the relevant triangle commute.

Now, an object in $(A/a)/c$ is a pair $(a'\to a, p : (f(a')\to f(a))\to (b\to f(a)))$ where $a'\to a\in A/a$ and $p$ is a morphism of $B/f(a)$. Notice that since $f$ is fully faithful, the data of $a'\to a$ is irrelevant, since the source of $p$ is $f(a')\to f(a)$ and thus this comes from a uniquely determined $a'\to a$. So really objects can be identified with commutative triangles (drawn as a square for convenience)

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
f(a') @>>> b\\
@VVV @VVV  \\
f(a) @= f(a)
\end{CD}

And then a morphism in $(A/a)/c$ will be given by a map $a'\to a''$ making certain diagrams commute, which by fully faithfulness can be equivalently given by a map $f(a')\to f(a'')$ making the correct diagram commutes. To be more precise, the following diagram should commute :

$\hspace{5cm}$[image: commutative diagram of a morphism in (A/a)/c]

But then, the triangle given by $c:b\to f(a)$, $1_b:b\to b, c:b\to f(a)$ is a final object in $(A/a)/c$. Indeed we have a diagram like this for any $a'\in A$, and unicity of the map $f(a')\to b$ is direct :

$\hspace{5cm}$[image: terminal object in (A/a)/c]

And earlier in the paper it was shown that if a category has a final object, it is aspheric (follows easily from the definitions) so that $(A/a)/c$ is aspheric. Now, I don't ever use the assumptions that $f$ is aspheric so I certainly doubt that this proof is valid, but I can't tell where it goes wrong. Surely there's a blunder I'm missing, so I'd appreciate any pointer.

Comment: I read the post again. I've found why the argument is wrong, I will add an answer later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the "proof" above, I claimed $(A/a)/c$ has a final object given by the triangle $(1_b,c,c)$ but there no reason for this thing to even be an object of $(A/a)/c$ as described. Indeed for this to be the case, $b$ would need to be in the image of $f$ so the proof would work I guess for functors inducing a surjection on objects. So indeed, one would have to use the assumption of asphericity to get to the desired result.